# use app image data on not respectable websites

Tags: javascript, canvas, getimagedata

I use canvas.getImageData to get the colour of one pixel in a HTML/js canvas.
If it isn't an respectable website it is load on, it won't do it, because of cross-origin data.
But I can't make the website respectable, because I want to open it as HTML document on my device, to be able, to open it offline. 
I load images into the canvas, but when you don't have internet, it will load the image saved in localStorage (as dataURL).
Thanks for your attention
I'm happy about every answer which might help

Comment: This is impossible, as it would be a security risk. The image may contain confidential data only available through browser cookies, thus allowing you to see the image data would be equally bad as sharing your cookies. You can either host the image locally or configure CORS.

Comment: But hosting it from the device isn't respectable as well. The problem is, that the HTML data is not respectable, so loading the image isn't a problem.Maybe you can change the settings in chrome?  I activated the CORS, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: You can fetch it with `fetch` with CORS enabled, then draw it as a blob url

Comment: Nope, you can in Firefox though

Comment: can you give an example please? I don't really know how to do that. You can write it as answere.

Comment: My problem is, that the HTML FILE WITH MY CODE isn't respectable when I open it. Also, I recognized, that the toDataURL function isn't working, if the file isn't respectable.

Comment: Well, my answer shows how to generate a blob url, which is always considered same-origin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to load cross-origin images. First is using `fetch` and blob:

```
let image_url = await(await fetch(url, mode='cors')).blob();
let image = new Image;
image.url = image_url;
```

The other option is to set `crossOrigin=anynymous` on the image element:

```
downloadedImg = new Image;
downloadedImg.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
downloadedImg.addEventListener("load", imageReceived, false);
downloadedImg.src = imageURL;
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image

Comment: if you don't need to get the URL of the canvas, it should be working